# How do I log in to a telegram account via sms and also withdraw tdate or session via node.js?

Tags: node.js, authentication, bots, telegram, node-telegram-bot-api

How do I log in to a telegram account via sms and also withdraw tdate or session via node.js? I will be very grateful. It is necessary that when a user enters a code in my bot with telegram, then his account is logged in and also the tdata or session format is withdrawn. Bot on the node-telegram-botapi library, node.js . I will be grateful if you give at least a link to the library.

I didn't find anything on the Internet, I really need your help.